# How to get the current terminal name?

Tags: bash, terminal

How do I fetch the current terminal name?

I mean to the name that `ps` shows in the TTY column, e.g.:

```
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install/do/install# ps aux | egrep 'mysql|(^USER)'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dor       2238  0.2  1.9 448052 79796 ?        S    17:27   0:17 gedit /home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install/do/install/mysql.install /home/dor/Documents/LAMP_setup/webs_install/do/install/mysql.setup
root      4975  0.1  0.5 324984 22876 ?        S    18:12   0:04 gedit /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
root      8160  0.0  0.0   4108   664 pts/2    S    19:08   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --ledir=/usr/local/mysql/libexec
mysql     8279  0.0  0.4 146552 19032 pts/2    Sl   19:08   0:00 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/var --user=mysql --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/var/dor-desktop.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/var/dor-desktop.pid --socket=/usr/local/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
root      8342  0.0  0.0   7632  1024 pts/2    R+   19:14   0:00 egrep --color=auto mysql|(^USER)
```

In the above example, I need to fetch `pts/2` which is probably the name for the current terminal that executed those commands.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270272/how-to-get-the-tty-in-which-bash-is-running/270372

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
tty
```

Now I have to enter 30 characters where 3 would have been enough... :-)

Comment: `apropos tty` might have been instructive, too (-:

Comment: @tripleee If you know the result getting it usually seems easy. But this was a really hard one. I should upvote the question in order to kick him above the 125 rep points border so the he can offer the deserved bounty for my great effort...

Comment: Your answer got me wondering *where* `tty` gets the name of the PTY or TTY.  I ran `strace -o spork tty` to find out that it does a readlink on a /proc file: `readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/5"..., 4095) = 10`  It's great that /proc can be used to do such nifty things, but what did earlier Unixes, without a flexible /proc filesystem, do to get tty name?

Comment: You could simply explain what that command, is, what it does and what else you can do with it and whoooosh, it would be a better answer.

Comment: @Bobby Every answer can be made better. The questioner got his problem solved after two minutes; not so bad IMHO. Seriously, I have no idea what else you can do with `tty`. What it does is exactly what the question is about. I don't even get the difference between "what that command is" and "what it does". What "is" a command? But, hey, I don't want upvotes for nothing. If you write a clearly better answer (which mine may have prevented) then I will give a 50 rep bounty for that (as soon as it's possible i.e. in two days).

Comment: @BruceEdiger Give it a try: Make that a new question, throw a 500 bounty at it and hope it doesn't get killed as OT ;-)

Comment: I  took tty id by `basename $(tty)`

Answer (score 4):

Re: "You could simply explain what that command, is, what it does and what else you can do with it and whoooosh, it would be a better answer. –  Bobby"

The Unix name of the current terminal (or console, as we oldsters use to sometimes also call it) is: /dev/tty which, can be used to easily create a new multi-line file from the command prompt thusly: cp /dev/tty README.md (hitting then puts the cursor on a new blank line where you can enter text, hit return again, enter a second line, etcetera. When finished entering lines, do a control-d which causes the cp command to exit and you will have made a multi-line file with a single command).

Comment: The "name" tty is derived from TeleType (the original terminal Device) which also explains why it is in the /dev dir.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187319/how-to-get-the-real-name-of-the-controlling-terminal

Comment: That's a neat trick.

Answer (score 1):

Re: "You could simply explain what that command, is, what it does and what else you can do with it and whoooosh, it would be a better answer. – Bobby"

**OR** we could really go crazy, and say "go look at the source code for more information."  So I did.

To actually get the name in [`tty.c`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tty.c#L79), an auxilliary function [`ttyname`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tty.c#L123) is called on `STDIN_FILENO`.  Both of these are defined in `unistd.h` (for proof, run `grep "STDIN_FILENO\|ttyname" /usr/include/unistd.h`), which is pulled into `tty.c` through [`#include "system.h"`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tty.c#L29) (go [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/system.h#L34) to see
`system.h`).

Now `ttyname` is an external dependency defined in [`glib_c/sysdeps/posix/ttyname.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/ttyname.c;h=e851e659145685e141c19b45d0c337a17796b850;hb=HEAD#l98).  It, in turn, `fstats` file descriptor `STDIN_FILENO` (`0`), and uses the function [`gettyname`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/ttyname.c;h=e851e659145685e141c19b45d0c337a17796b850;hb=HEAD#l37) to actually retrieve a pointer to the name of the tty.  `fstat` ends up leading to an [`INLINE_SYSCALL`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h.html#_M/INLINE_SYSCALL) in [`fxstat.c`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fxstat.c.html#39), which ends up invoking an [`internal_syscall2`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h.html#_M/internal_syscall2), and at this point I'm outta luck.  I don't really know what that does.

But, I believe it invokes the `stat` functionality on `fd 0`.  It does all this, making sure not to stop at "stdin" or something like that.  Either way, you can achieve the same behavior by looking at

```
stat /dev/stdin # -> /proc/self/fd/0
stat /proc/self/fd/0 # -> /dev/pts/<some number>
```

Then `/dev/pts/<some number>` is your `tty`.

**Update**

I'm trying to get to the bottom of it all, but I won't be as detailed as above.  So far I've deduced that the `syscall` indirection ends up at a function called `vfs_fstat` which then calls the function `fdget_raw` which immediately calls `__fget_light`.  This uses a macro `current` which returns the result of `get_current` defined here:

```
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{                                                           
    return this_cpu_read_stable(current_task);              
}
```

Anyways, the `task_struct` has an entry `files` of type `files_struct`, which I guess keeps the list of `files` relevant to the current task.  This is an array, and `fd` is an index into the array.  To wrap all this up, we just need to find out what `fd 0` really means in reference to this array (i.e. when a task is created, what actually gets put there).  Then, we just need to see in the source if `/proc/self` accurately reflects that array, then we can be sure that what we think happens actually happens...

Answer (score 0):

There is also Shell Parameter Expansion using the `@P` Operator.
You can get the terminal device similar to `$PS1` conventions:

```
$myvar='\l'
echo ${myvar@P}
```

This will expand `\l` to the basename of the current terminal device.

Reference: man bash